# Arduino Due maximum interrupt frequency

Tags: c++, arduino, microcontroller, gnu, processor

I am trying to implement my own SPI communication from FPGA to Arduino, in which my FPGA serve as MASTER and generate Chip enable and clock for communication. FPGA transmit data at its rising edge and receive data at its falling edge my FPGA code works properly.

In Arduino side I capture this master clock on interrupts and receive data at its rising edge and transmit at its falling edge but communication does not work properly if I increase clock speed from 10 KHz.

According to my understanding, Arduino Due works at 84 MHz and handling 1 MHz interrupts is not a big problem. Can you tell me how I can handle this high-speed clock with an Arduino Due?

Arduino code below:

```
void ISR1();
// this constant won't change
const int  S_CLK = 19; //  slow clock in this case FPGA is master
const int  MOSI_C =  51; //   Master out slave in in this case arduino
//receive data from FPGA
const int  MISO_C = 50; //  Master in slave out in this case arduino
//transmit data from FPGA
const int  SS_C = 53; // the pin that the pushbutton is attached to
const int TRANS_INDEX = 32; //index that is used to transmit data in this
cas 32 bits are transmitted
const int REC_INDEX = 48;

#define CLK_MAIN    84000000UL

//Variables will change

int ss_check = 0; //used for reading of slave select
int mosi_data[REC_INDEX + 2]; //delcare receiving data array length
int count = 0; //used for convertion of bits to bytes
int index_r_stat = 0; //give us a value of status that
how much bits are received
int flag = 0; //used for stop reading s
int miso_out[TRANS_INDEX] = {
  1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0
};
int miso_index = 0; //used for above array
int last_clk_state = 1; //used for the detection of rising and
falling edge

int check_clk;
void setup() {
  //   initialize the button pin as a input
  pinMode(S_CLK , INPUT);
  pinMode(MOSI_C , INPUT);
  pinMode(MISO_C , OUTPUT);
  pinMode(SS_C , INPUT);
  //   initialize serial communication
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  //   read the pushbutton input pin
  ss_check = digitalRead(SS_C);
  //Serial.println(ss_check);
  //WAIT until slave select is not read
  if (ss_check == 0) {
    //attach interrupt so that data is
    attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(S_CLK), ISR1, CHANGE);
  }
  if ((index_r_stat == (REC_INDEX + 1)) && (flag == 0)) {
    for (int i = 1; i < (REC_INDEX + 1); i = i + 1) {
      Serial.print(mosi_data[i]);
      flag = 1;
      if (count < 7) {
        count = count + 1;
      } else {
        count = 0;
        Serial.println();
      }
    }
  }
}

void ISR1() {
  if ((last_clk_state == 1) && (digitalRead(S_CLK) == 0)) {
    check_clk = 0;
    //this code is used to transmit data to FPGA
    if (miso_index < TRANS_INDEX - 1) {
      digitalWrite(MISO_C, miso_out[miso_index]);
      miso_index = miso_index + 1;
    } else {
      miso_index = miso_index;
    }
  } else {
    check_clk = 1;
    //this code is used for reading data from FPGA
    if (index_r_stat < (REC_INDEX + 1)) {
      mosi_data[index_r_stat] = digitalRead( MOSI_C);
      index_r_stat = index_r_stat + 1;
    } else {
      detachInterrupt(S_CLK);
      index_r_stat = index_r_stat;
    }
  }
  last_clk_state = digitalRead(S_CLK);
}
```

Comment: Software emulation is always slow. You should use hardware SPI instead

Comment: There is a firehose problem in this code, the Arduino can't send the SPI data any faster than 9600 baud.  Which is indeed 10 KHz.  If the FPGA sends any faster than that, and doesn't delay long enough after REC_INDEX bytes, then it will start overwriting bytes in the buffer.  Or you'll lose bytes, using attachInterrupt() on-the-fly is pretty tricky.

Answer (score 0):

Your ISR subroutine could be a limiting factor in achieving higher SPI speeds, especially if it's not optimized for fast execution. Yes, Arduino Due's CPU runs at 84 MHZ, but is your ISR routine going to execute in only 84 cc to achieve 1MHZ?? I think you code you listed above needs somewhere in the magnitude of 100-1000CC. so you are capped at 84KHZ of the clock cycle. Also the ISR on rising and falling edges. So split that by 2.

You should try and optimize the routine by direct register access instead of using Arduino library functions (e.g., digitalRead() and digitalWrite()), consider accessing GPIO registers directly for faster read and write operations. This can significantly reduce overhead and improve ISR performance. Another thing, optimize data processing by streamlining your data processing within the ISR to minimize latency. If possible, maybe allocate time only for writing and others for reading. You can read one byte and then write one byte. Also, see if you can use the SPI library buffer that uses the SPI hardware. so you can read in bytes instead of bits.

Comment: @Fastnlight, thanks for your comments but I wrote this answer by myself. I understand AI-generated content is not allowed